# can anyone help how to use cookies to store column width by using material table in angular?

Tags: angular, cookies, reload, mat-table

when i refresh the page i am unable to get the resized column width instead of getting same column width as mentioned in css file. can anyone suggest me how to use cookies for this, below is my code:
when i refresh the page i am unable to get the resized column width instead of getting same column width as mentioned in css file. can anyone suggest me how to use cookies for this, below is my code:

```
    import { variable } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
    import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';
    import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ){}
    
      title = 'mat-table-resizeEvent';
      displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
    
       cookieValue1 : string;
       cookieValue2 : string;
       cssValue : string;
       
       
      ngOnInit(): void { 
        //console.log( localStorage.getItem('cookie'));
        console.log( this.cookieValue1 = this.cookieService.get('width'));
        console.log( this.cookieValue2 = this.cookieService.get('column'));
    
        //this.cookieService.get('width');
      }
      
    
        onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent, columnName): void {
            if (event.edges.right) {
                this.cssValue = event.rectangle.width + 'px';
                const columnElts = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-column-' + columnName);
                for (let i = 0; i < columnElts.length; i++) {
                    const currentEl = columnElts[i] as HTMLDivElement;
            currentEl.style.width = this.cssValue;
           //localStorage.setItem('cookies', this.cssValue );
           //localStorage.setItem('cookie', JSON.stringify(cssValue));
           this.cookieService.set( 'width', this.cssValue );
           this.cookieService.set( 'column', columnName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    export interface Element {
      name: string;
      position: number;
      weight: number;
      symbol: string;
    }
    
    const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
      {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
      {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
      {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
      {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
      {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
      {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
      {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
      {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
      {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
      {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
      {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
      {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
      {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
      {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
      {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
      {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
      {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
      {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
      {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
      {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
    ];
```

```
    <h1>
      MATERIAL TABLE
    </h1>
    
    <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mwlResizable  [enableGhostResize]="false" (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event, column)"
                 [resizeEdges]="{bottom: false, right: true, top: false, left: true}">
                    {{ column | uppercase }}
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item[column] }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <div>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        </div>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
            
        </mat-table>
    </div>
```

````
```
p {
    font-family: Lato;
  }
  
  .example-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 500px;
    min-width: 300px;
  }
  
  .mat-table {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
  }
  
      mwlResizable {
          box-sizing: border-box; 
      }
  
        mat-cell,
      mat-footer-cell,
      mat-header-cell {
          width: 200px;
          word-break: break-all;
          flex:none;
          display: block;
      }
     
  
      .mat-header-cell {
  
          padding-left: 12px;
          padding-right: 12px;
          line-height: 46px;
          border-left: 2px solid #f8f7f7;
  
      }
  
          .mat-sort-header-button {
              white-space: nowrap;
              overflow: hidden;
              text-overflow: ellipsis;
          }
      
      .mat-cell {
          padding-left: 12px;
          padding-right: 12px;
          border-left: 2px solid #f8f7f7;
      }
  
      .mat-cell {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
          line-height: 2.6em;
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
      
  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

use `localStorage` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp. It can only save `string` but it is suitable to save small data easily. One little drawback, it can only save strings.

You can save it like `localStorage.setItem('columnWidth', width);` and you can read the value then convert it to a number like `let width = Number(localStorage.getItem('columnWidth'));`

In the HTML code, you can inject your values like `[style.width]="columnWidth + 'px'"`

Comment: thanks bt when i refresh the page again  it will set to original width. i want like when i resize the column and refresh the page i should take the updated resized colum width.

Comment: Ok, then you should use that `cssValue` in somewhere HTML code. You should somehow inject it into HTML to see the change.

Comment: sir i am not getting how to implement cssValue in HTML file can u please suggest me to how to implement...

Comment: In the HTML code, you can inject your values like `[style.width]="columnWidth + 'px'"`